# Error 15507 when restoring full backup

Tags: sql-server-2014

Trying to recover a full backup of a database (Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU4-GDR) (KB4583462)) gives the following error:

> Msg 15507, Level 16, State 30, Line 2
> A key required by this operation appears to be corrupted.

I have created a master key on the destination server and I copied and created the TDE certificate from the source server.

Answer (score 1):

When you backup & restore the encryption key, you need to make sure you are backing it up with a private key & password:

```sql
BACKUP CERTIFICATE MyDatabaseEncryptionCert
    TO FILE = 'E:\Backup\MyDatabaseEncryptionCert.cer'
    WITH PRIVATE KEY(
        FILE = 'E:\Backup\MyDatabaseEncryptionCert.prvk',
        ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'NotPassword1!'
        );
```

And on the target server, you'll use the mirrored statement to create it from that file:

```sql
CREATE CERTIFICATE MyDatabaseEncryptionCert
    FROM FILE = 'E:\Backup\MyDatabaseEncryptionCert.cer'
    WITH PRIVATE KEY(
        FILE = 'E:\Backup\MyDatabaseEncryptionCert.prvk',
        ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'NotPassword1!'
        );
```

If the encryption certificate is backed up without a private key (which itself is encrypted with a password), then SQL Server considers the encryption certificate backup to be untrusted. As a result, you see a 15507 error when attempting to make use of it.

Moving the cert (again) using the above method should resolve the error when restoring the TDE-encrypted backup.